# Springfox - Schema for Interfaces Empty

Tags: java, jackson, springfox

I am using springfox 3.0.0, and I have an interface that is used as a `@RequestBody`.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

SwaggerConfig.java

```
class SwaggerConfig {

  @Bean
  Docket api() {
    return new Docket(OAS_30)
      .select()
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(
          "org.springframework.boot").negate())
      .build();
    }
  }
```

Models

```
//assume Lombok or standard getter/setters/constructors
class Clazz implements StringInterface {
  String s;
  Integer i; 
}

@JsonDeserialize(as = Clazz.class)
interface StringInterface {
  String getString();
}
```

In Springfox 2.9.* the schema for `StringInterface` was

```
{
  "title": "StringInterface",
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
     "s": {
       "type": "String"
    }
  }
}
```

When I upgrade to 3.0.0, however, the schema is now empty.

```
{
  "title": "StringInterface",
  "type": "object"
}
```

Regular classes are displayed correctly. It seems to a problem only with interfaces.

Comment: What dependencies are you using ? Can you show your swagger configurtion

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a workaround. Unfortunately, it requires some configuration for every interface involved.

```
@JsonDeserialize(as = Clazz.class)
interface StringInterface {
  static class Model {
    String getString();
  }
}
```

SwaggerConfig.java
class SwaggerConfig {

```
  @Bean
  Docket api() {
    return new Docket(OAS_30)
      .select()
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(
          "org.springframework.boot").negate())
      .directModelSubstitute(StringInterface.class, StringInterface.Model.class)
      .build();
  }

  @Component
  @Order(SwaggerPluginSupport.SWAGGER_PLUGIN_ORDER)
  static class ModelDeclaringClassName implements TypeNameProviderPlugin {
    boolean supports(DocumentationType delimiter) {
      return true;
  }

  String nameFor(type: Class<?>) {
    Class<?> actualClass = type.getSimpleName().equals("Model") ? 
      type.getDeclaringClass() :
      type;
  
      return type.getSimpleName();
    }
  }
}
```

My application was actually in Kotlin, so the `directModelSubstitute` calls can be simplified like this:

```
private inline fun <reified T> Docket.substituteModel() =
    T::class.java.let {
        directModelSubstitute(
            it,
            it.declaredClasses.first { c ->
                c.simpleName == "Model"
            }
        )
    }
```

Usage like this:

```
.substituteModel<StringInterface>()
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend switching to SpringDoc.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The latest version as of now, 1.5.6 would give you the following schema for your interface

```
{
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
     "string": {
       "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

You would also have to setup the config class a little differently & annotate your controllers with @RestController. I have not personally, ever seen usage of an interface as a RequestBody so, this case is a little strange.

However, if your set on using your dependency version then, its something to do with how swagger schema generation is interpreting your JsonDeserialization I would think.

Comment: This has the same problem as Springfox